# regex to find comma followed by either curly brackets or regular brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a JavaScript issue, and due to a few circumstances, I can't debug JavaScript properly. I have the feeling that the issue might be because there is a comma (,) before a ] or }
I could have a line break or not between the comma and the bracket.
So I wanted to do a search for that. I'm not really good at writing regex, but I'm sure there's a simple one that will help me with that. 
I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[]` character class construct to provide an option between the two characters. Here is the regex:

```
,\n?[\]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

using a a lookahead, you can check for it with:

```
(?=,[\]\}]),
(?=....) 'positive lookahead, meaning that it will only match if text is followed by this
   ,[\]\}] is your lookahead pattern, this one means a comma followed by a ] or }
           , matches for the comma
```